# Node Js Authorization

Tags: node.js, mongoose

[This is my mongoose schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGE5I.png)

I have enter passwordChangedAt: in the postman but it is not showing
[Here you can see passwordChangedAt is not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxUlg.png)
[Even I can not acess decoded.iat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prHIb.png)

i was expecting normal working

Answer (score 0):

Change this
PasswordChangeAt: Date
to
PasswordChangeAt: {type:Date};

Keep me updated

Comment: I have tried that too still not working